# dygraphs, Exclude NAN NULL values from rolling average

Tags: dygraphs

With dyGraph, when a value in set to NAN or NULL the value is not plotted.  However, if the roll value is set to a number greater than 1 the gaps begin to get smaller.  Basically the NULL/NAN is somehow used in the rolling average.  For example, if there are five time periods without data the and the roll value is 10 the spaces doesn't show up. A roll value of 2 leaves a 3 period gap.

Is there any way to always make sure the data gaps remain the proper length?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior.

Say you have daily data and a gap of five days. When you set `rollPeriod: 10`, dygraphs will average whatever values it finds in the last ten days to produce each data point. If there are five missing days, some of the values will be the average of only five days, not ten. This behavior will obviously smooth over gaps, something which is typically desirable.

If you want a different behavior, you'll have to modify the data on your own before passing it to dygraphs to be charted.